# Initiating a phone call

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible yet to initiate a phone call? E.g. if I'm making a branch finder action a dialogue might go like:

```
"Hi, where's my nearest store?"
"Your nearest store is our Oxford Street branch, at 300 Oxford St, Marylebone."
"Call it"
"Sure"
```

It then initiates a call to the store, like an Android app using an [ACTION_DIAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) intent.

I would think something like this *should* be possible, especially considering the current devices supporting Assistant are phones and Google Home, both of which can make calls (I guess future devices with assistant built in might not, but then there can be a check like `app.phoneCapabilities`). I've tried using `.addSuggestionLink` with a `tel:` address with no luck.

Comment: I want to do the same but i got errors, please help me show some code  or any documentation. Open this link issues i am facing https://stackoverflow.com/q/60596851/10744950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually made a dodgy work around for this, if anyone comes back to this and is interested.

You can suggest a webpage URL, which can be a page which has a `tel:` link from there. Either using server side work or just simple JavaScript (mine uses simple JavaScript), you can update the link.

My link is below - feel free to use it, I use it in my app. It's pretty basic, the documentation is in the comments:

https://domdomegg.github.io/linkgenerator?href=tel%3A%2B442070313000&bgcolor=607d8b&buttontext=Click%20to%20call%20Google

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the Google Home cannot (yet) make calls. That feature was announced at I/O and will be rolling out later this year. It is not yet known if there will be API access to that feature when it does roll out. (There is certainly potential for abuse of the feature, although there are some ways that can mitigate that abuse.)

I haven't tested, but I'm a little surprised that the `tel:` url form didn't work since I thought that would just launch an intent on Android (tho I don't know how iOS would handle it) and tel: goes to the dialer intent.

Comment: Ah didn't know that about Google Home. Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can show a call button which will redirect to the specified number on the dialer app.

Here's a way to do that from **fulfillment response**:

```
"buttons": [
   {
    "title": "Call",
    "openUrlAction": {
        "url": "tel:+91123456789",
        "androidApp": {
            "packageName": "com.android.phone"
        },
        "versions": []
    }
  }
]
```

Add this JSON to your response and it will show a button which will redirect to **default call app** and shows `+91123456789` number filled.

**EXTRA**

Similarly, if you want to send mail then you can add:

```
{
    "title": "Send Mail to Jay",
    "openUrlAction": {
        "url": "mailto:Jp9573@gmail.com",
        "androidApp": {
            "packageName": "android.intent.extra.EMAIL"
        },
        "versions": []
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to show call button and open the dialer as well. The only problem I have now is call button is a circle with white background. Seems like it has a icon missing, can you help me here ?

Comment: I got error when i tried above code please open this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596851/issue-in-make-a-phone-call-within-google-assistant-app