# Make a phone call within Google Assistant App

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am trying to develop a Google Assistant App, primarily for Google Home and Google Assistant on the phone.

Is there a way to integrate Google's hands-free calling capability to the Assistant App, so that a user can directly initiate a phone call within my app?

For example. my app is providing a few suggestions for some stores, and will prompt the user to ask if they would like to make a call to a store.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Many Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know this is not supported right now. But I also wish this (and the ability to call other apps like navigation or text messaging and so forth) were available for us to use.

Comment: if we can make call by google assistant why not i can initiate call by an app made for google assistant using dialogflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initiating a phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133896/initiating-a-phone-call)

Comment: I want to do the same but i got errors, please help me show some code  or any documentation. Open this link issues i am facing https://stackoverflow.com/q/60596851/10744950

Answer (score 3):

You can show a call button which will redirect to the specified number on the dialer app.

Here's a way to do that from **fulfillment response**:

```
"buttons": [
   {
    "title": "Call",
    "openUrlAction": {
        "url": "tel:+91123456789",
        "androidApp": {
            "packageName": "com.android.phone"
        },
        "versions": []
    }
  }
]
```

Add this JSON to your response and it will show a button which will redirect to **default call app** and shows `+91123456789` number filled.

**EXTRA**

Similarly, if you want to send mail then you can add:

```
{
    "title": "Send Mail to Jay",
    "openUrlAction": {
        "url": "mailto:Jp9573@gmail.com",
        "androidApp": {
            "packageName": "android.intent.extra.EMAIL"
        },
        "versions": []
    }
}
```

Comment: I trying to add this button in a Basic Card but it does not show. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Add one more empty object(for i.e. `{}`) in button array. and try it

Comment: I got it, is there a way to attach a Icon to that button

Comment: also, is there documentation where this solution is taken from ? I would like to know more.

Comment: You can refer https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#basiccard

Comment: thanks Jay. problem I am facing is that card shows buttons in white circle. any suggestion on how to counter that  ?

Comment: I didn't get you.. buttons show in a white circle means? It seems that it's different problem itself, you can ask a new question, that would be helpful to others also

Comment: I got error when i tried above code please open this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596851/issue-in-make-a-phone-call-within-google-assistant-app

Comment: The above code  is not working for google assistant