# Issue in make a phone call within Google Assistant App

Tags: actions-on-google

I try to implement button in basic card i got an error

> API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: "(expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].basic_card.buttons[0].open_url_action) versions: Cannot find field." HTTP Status Code: 200.

```
 conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    text: `This is a basic card.  Text in a basic card can include "quotes" and`,
    subtitle: 'This is a subtitle',

    buttons: [
     {
      "title": "Call",
      "openUrlAction": {
          "url": "tel:+91123456789",
          "androidApp": {
              "packageName": "com.android.phone"
          },
          "versions": []
       }
    },
   ],
    "formattedText": "Some text",
    image: new Image({
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
      alt: 'Image alternate text',
    }),
    "title": "Card Title"
  }));
```

and I tried all the ways add another empty object in button array also same error:

```
buttons: [
     {
      "title": "Call",
      "openUrlAction": {
          "url": "tel:+91123456789",
          "androidApp": {
              "packageName": "com.android.phone"
          },
          "versions": []
       }
    },
  {}
   ],
```

Tried code below got error:

> expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].basic_card.buttons[0].open_url_action: the protocol must be http or https.

```
buttons: new Button({
      "title": "button text",
      'url': "tel:+91123456789",
      "androidApp": {
        "packageName": "com.android.phone"
      }
})
```

got response in action console simulator:

```
"buttons": [
                  {
                    "title": "button text",
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "url": "tel:+919177723773"
                    }
                  }
           ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL property that you are using includes a phonenumber. The link property can only use links to a [webpage](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#basic_card). This also comes back in the error message that you are getting:

"*the protocol must be http or https.*".

So if you want to fix the error, you need to include a http or https link in your button instead of a phonenumber.

As for calling a phonenumber from the Google Assistant App, I'm not sure if this feature is supported at the moment.

Comment: But i want to make call to the number when user click on button how can do this

Comment: Implemented code base on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985056/10744950 pls open this link

Comment: Thank you for your response. Button is not showed in card. simulator response in action console    `buttons": [
                  {
                    "title": "This is a button",
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "androidApp": {
                        "packageName": "com.android.phone"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],`

Comment: @Prisoner confirmed my earlier thought, adding a ```tel:``` URL is not supported for Google Assistant, I've reverted my answer to the first post.

Comment: means there is no option to implementign tel: in google assistant

Comment: No this isn't possible using a ```tel:```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a `tel:` URL through the Assistant.

As the error noted:

> expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].basic_card.buttons[0].open_url_action: the protocol must be http or https.

Keep in mind that the Assistant runs on devices that do not support `tel:` URLs, even if they support `https:` URLs.

Comment: FYI, There is an answer by you in the link added by the OP which mentions that you expected it to work. Made me think it had to be possible if you said it :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134734/6351280

Comment: *facepalm* I had totally forgotten about that post. Apparently they're now enforcing the URL type and never implemented tel: on speakers.